# Use pandas to cluster in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, cluster-analysis

I need help in order to deal with pandas and tab 
Here is a tab :

```
Col1    Col2
A   B
C   B
D   B
E   F
G   F
F   A
Z   Y
H   Y
L   P
```

From this tab I would like to create clusters and get a new tab such as:

```
Cluster Names
Cluster1    A
Cluster1    B
Cluster1    C
Cluster1    D
Cluster1    F
Cluster1    E
Cluster1    G
Cluster2    Z
Cluster2    Y
Cluster2    H
Cluster3    L
Cluster3    P
```

As you can see the letters `A B C D E F` and `G` are in the `Cluster1` because they all have something in common.

```
`A` and `B` are in the same line (A and B forme the `Cluster1`)
`C` and `B` are in the same line (C includes the `Cluster1`)
`D` and `B` are in the same line (D includes the `Cluster1`)
`F` and `A` are in the same line (F includes the `Cluster1`)
`E` and `F` are in the same line (E includes the `Cluster1`)
`G` and `F` are in the same line (G includes the `Cluster1`)

`Z` and `Y` are in the same line (Z and Y create the `Cluster2`)
`H` and `Y` are in the same line (H includes the `Cluster2`)

`L` and `P` are in the same line (L and P create the `Cluster3`)
```

Does someone have an idea using pandas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a graph problem know as [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)), I suggest you use [networkx.connected_components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components):

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Col1', target='Col2', create_using=nx.Graph)

for component in nx.connected_components(g):
    print(component)
```

**Output**

```
{'E', 'G', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'B'}
{'Y', 'H', 'Z'}
{'L', 'P'}
```

Notice that the components match the groups of your output. To convert it to a DataFrame do the following:

```
data = [[f'Cluster{i}', element] for i, component in enumerate(nx.connected_components(g), 1) for element in component]

result = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Cluster', 'Names'])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     Cluster Names
0   Cluster1     D
1   Cluster1     A
2   Cluster1     B
3   Cluster1     G
4   Cluster1     C
5   Cluster1     F
6   Cluster1     E
7   Cluster2     Z
8   Cluster2     Y
9   Cluster2     H
10  Cluster3     L
11  Cluster3     P
```

Comment: Ok thank you but how to change it into a dabatframe and name the clusters ? (One column for the cluster name and one for the letter name)?